# Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 with SAS token Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to connec to to ADLS Gen 2 container with Power BI, but I've only found the option to connect with the key1/2 from the container (active directory is not an option in this case).

However, I don't want to use those keys since they are stored in Power BI and it can be seeing for the people who will have the .pbix file.

Is there anyway to connect to the ADLS Gen 2 from Power BI using Shared Access Signature (SAS)? so I can control only read access to what is really needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way is to use the Storage Key, however I don't think the Key can be read or seen by the user after the Storage Data Source is applied and saved. It can be changed, but the Key itself is shown as dotted secret.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it ;-)
I've tested it with Parquet files but CSV format should work as well. In PBI Desktop:

1. Select your source file type
2. Construct your whole file path with Advanced option. This will give you an opportunity to provide more than one part of the whole path.
3. Replace "blob" part of the URL with "dfs".
4. Paste your SAS token to the second text box
5. You should be ready to rock.